# Field homomorphism $\phi: F \to F$ with $F$ extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ is identity map

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

While reviewing exercises for introduction to algebra final I came across the following question: Consider a field extension $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}.$ Now suppose we have a field homomorphism $\phi: F\to F $ Prove that for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ one has $\phi(x)=x.$ There was also a follow up question where we considered $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2021}).$ We needed to determine all the field isomorphisms $\phi: F \to F $, and prove that they were isomorphisms.

Now I don't know how to tackle this problem. I know a field homomorphism is by definition injective, so in the first part $\phi: F\to F $ is an isomorphism. I don't really know what to do with that information.

Comment: Let $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. Show that $f(\phi(\alpha))=\phi(f(\alpha))=0$ too. Hence, this limits the number of values $\phi(2021^{1/4})$ can attain. Furthermore, $\phi$ is uniquely defined once we know $\phi(2021^{1/4})$.

Comment: It is **not** true that a field homomorphism is necessarily an isomorphism. Take $F = \Bbb{R}(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$, the field of rational functions over the reals in a countably infinite number of indeterminates. Then the map $x_i \mapsto x_{2i}$ on the indeterminates induces a field homomorphism $F \to F$ that is not an isomorphism.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean when you say "We needed to determine all .... and prove that they were isomorphisms." Did you mean all homomorphisms $\phi:F\to F$ are isomorphisms, where $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2021})$?

Comment: @RobArthan We've seen that a field homomorphism is always injective. My reasoning was just because because it's injective and its a field homomorphism onto itself then its an isomorphism. Where does this reasoning fail? Is it because its not a finite field?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak The literal question was: Consider $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2021}).$ Determine all field isomorphisms $\phi: F \to F.$ If you claim that its a field isomorphism, prove it.

Comment: You aren't given that $\phi$ is surjective: the $\phi$ you are given maps $F$ to itself, but not necessarily onto itself, and hence doesn't have to be an isomorphisms, e.g., as in the example I gave in my comment. (However this is irrelevant to proving that $\Bbb{Q}$ is fixed under $\phi$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof of $\forall x\in\mathbb Q\colon\phi(x)=x$ can be done "by hand" in the following manner:

- First note that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1)=1$ by definition of field homomorphism.
- From this we can deduce $\phi(n)=n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$ and actually every $n\in\mathbb Z$ since for field homomorphisms we know $\forall x\in\mathbb Q\colon\phi(-x)=-\phi(x)$.
- Now let $\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb Q$ with $p,q\in\mathbb Z$ and $q\neq0$. Then we have $q\cdot\phi\left(\frac pq\right)=\phi(q)\cdot\phi\left(\frac pq\right)=\phi\left(q\cdot\frac pq\right)=\phi(p)=p$ so we end up with $\phi\left(\frac pq\right)=\frac pq$ and are done.

This has actually shown that the automorphism group of $\mathbb Q$ is the trivial group and it's a fun exercise to prove the same for $\mathbb R$ (via checking that any such automorphism is order-preserving and following one of the routes mentioned in the comments).

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. How would one go about proving the same for $\mathbb{R}.$ Is it because we can decompose every real number as a sum of $a\cdot 10^k$ with $a \in \{0,1,\cdots , 9\}$ and since their image is all identical so should their summation and multiplication?

Comment: @rikdb: the argument for $\mathbb{R} $ is not obvious, but once mentioned it is easy to follow. The key is to prove that the automorphism on $\mathbb{R} $ must be continuous and then we can use the result that the map fixes rationals.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's not the solution I had in mind (and I can't see how to prove continuity directly): Another way is to show that the automorphism of $\mathbb R$ has to preserve the relation "$\le$" and then argue via (rational) sequences of nested intervals. Of course, in the end we see that it is continuous (because the identity is the only option), but I'm interested if you know a direct way to show continuity.

Comment: @localshop: fix arbitrary real $\epsilon >0$ and choose a rational $\delta$ with $0<\delta<\epsilon$. Any automorphism $\sigma$ must preserve order (you know the proof) and if $-\delta<y-x<\delta$ then applying $\sigma$ we get $-\delta<\sigma(y) - \sigma(x) <\delta$ and thus $|x-y|<\delta\implies |\sigma(x) - \sigma(y)|<\delta<\epsilon$. This shows that $\sigma$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of your exercise, we can do the following.

Suppose $\phi: F \to F$ is a field morphism, where $F = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2021})$. By the first question, since $F$ is a field extension of $\Bbb{Q}$, $\phi$ is the identity on $\Bbb{Q}$.

Now consider $2021 = \phi(2021) = \phi(\sqrt[4]{2021}^4) = \phi(\sqrt[4]{2021})^4$. Hence we only have two options for $\phi(\sqrt[4]{2021})$. It is either $\sqrt[4]{2021}$ or $-\sqrt[4]{2021}$ (note that the other two fourth roots are impossible since the image $\phi$ is, in particular, real).

Because the field extension is characterized by $\sqrt[4]{2021}$, its image fixes the entire morphism (every element in $F$ is written as some rational expression in $\sqrt[4]{2021}$). Hence there are exactly two morphisms; \begin{align}
&\phi_1: F \to F: \sqrt[4]{2021} \mapsto \sqrt[4]{2021} \\
&\phi_2: F \to F: \sqrt[4]{2021} \mapsto -\sqrt[4]{2021}
\end{align}
Note that both of these are isomorphisms (in fact, $\phi_1 = \operatorname{Id}$).